# Error A2032: invalid use of register while I'm trying to use an array

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to find why I'm getting this error, (A2032) while I'm trying to move through the array to use it. What the code does is pretty simple yet I can't find a way to make it work and as far as I know, the way I work with the array is correct (according to our teacher)

```
.386
.model flat, C
.code

isItValid PROC

push EBP
mov [EBP], ESP

push EAX  ; R1->R5
push EBX  ; TMP

ADD EBP, [EBP+8]

;1
MOV EBX, EBP+8
NOT EBX     ;NOT TMP
MOV EAX, EBX

;2
MOV EBX, EBP+4      ; EBX -> R2
OR EAX, EBX     ; OR TMP, R1

;3
MOV EBX, EBP +4     ; EBX -> R2
XOR EAX, EBX    ; XOR TMP, R2

;4
MOV EBX, EBP+4      ; EBX -> R3
NOT EBX     ; NOT R3
XOR EAX, EBX    ;XOR TMP, NOT(R3)
NOT EAX     ; NOT(TMP XOR NOT(R3))

;5
MOV EBX, EBP+4      ; EBX -> R4
OR EAX, EBX     ; TMP OR R4

;6
MOV EBX, EBP+4 ; EBX -> R5
CMP EAX, EBX

JZ CONS     
MOV EBX, 0  


CONS:
    MOV EBX, 1                      

POP EAX
POP EBX
POP EBP

ret
isItValid ENDP

END
```

Comment: When you get an error you should specify which lines the error messages refer to. That said, `MOV EBX, EBP+8` and all the other instructions like it are not valid x86 instructions. What are you trying to do with that instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line (and other similar ones)

```
MOV EBX, EBP+8
```

is an invalid use of the `EBP` register. You can't move a register value plus a constant to another register. If you are attempting to access the stack, the line needs to be like the one correctly implemented just above it

```
MOV EBX, [EBP+8]
```

Or, if your intention was to move `EBP+8` to `EBX`, like this

```
MOV EBX, EBP
ADD EBX, 8
```

Comment: The second variant could be written as `LEA EBX, [EBP+8]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it fixed the problem. Also AFAIK, the "return" value goes in EBX so if the whole process returns true, EBX should get a 1 by the time it gets popped out of the stack, right?

Comment: That won't do anything since you `POP EBX` afterwards and overwrite it, and I think it is more usual to return a value in EAX. I suggest you don't `PUSH/POP EAX` and return the value in `EAX`.